# Why are only two CPU cores used by a thread pool?

Tags: python

```
 for i in tqdm(range(N)):
        results_cmi.extend(Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(calculate_cmi_wrapper)(i, j, F, C) for j in range(N)))
```

[image]

Why are only two CPU cores used?

What can I do to to use all cores?

Comment: That is not the full code - include a runnable example including imports so we know what `Parallel` is. We can only assume it is joblib. Also, include some placeholder for calculate_cmi_wrapper

Comment: if using joblib, it might also be important to know which parallel backend you use (loky, threading, multiprocessing)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.